# Generating function and finite difference.

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, discrete-mathematics, self-learning, generating-functions

[image]

The above example is from Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis by John Riordan.

Here $\Delta$ is the difference operator.

But I am unable to understand why $\Delta 0^r = 1^r, \Delta^2 0^r = 2^r-2$ and $\Delta^3 0^r = 3^r - 3 \times 2^r +3$.

---

What I was trying is  $\Delta 0^r = (0+1)^r - 0^r = 1^r$, but then  $\Delta^2 0^r = \Delta 1^r = (1+1)^r - 1^r = 2^r - 1$, which is not matching with the book.

Comment: If $\Delta 0^r$ should be interpreted as $(\Delta(n \mapsto n^r))(0)$ then that is at the very least a confusing choice of notation.

Comment: @ronno can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I doubt I can explain anything, I am probably more confused about the notation than you are. The previous comment is more an expression of sympathy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riordan's notation is obscuring a lot, which makes things confusing. To make things clear, you need to understand that $\Delta$ operator takes in a sequence of numbers, and returns a new sequence of numbers. The notation $\Delta^2 0^r$, therefore, means the following, in plain English:

- Start with the sequence whose $i^\text{th}$ element is $i^r$. Let us call this sequence $s$.
- Apply $\Delta$ to this sequence, to get the sequence $\Delta(s)$, whose $i^\text{th}$ element is $(i+1)^r-i^r$.
- Apply $\Delta$ to the resulting sequence, to get $\Delta^2(s)$. The $i^\text{th}$ element of $\Delta^2(s)$ is
  $$
  \underbrace{\Big(((i+1)+1)^r-(i+1)^r\Big)}_{(i+1)^\text{st}\text{ element of $\Delta(s)$}}
  -\underbrace{\Big((i+1)^r-i^r\Big)}_{i^\text{th}\text{ element of $\Delta(s)$}}
  =(i+2)^r-2(i+1)^r+i^r$$
- Finally, $\Delta^2 0^r$ really means "the zeroth element of the sequence $\Delta^2(s)$". Evaluating the above expression at $i=0$, the result is $2^r-2\cdot 1^r+0^r=2^r-2$.

The same logic allows you to find $\Delta^30^r=3^r-3\cdot 2^r+2\cdot 1^r-0^r$.

Comment: This is like writing $\dfrac{d^2 1^n}{dx^2} = n(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert on the umbral calculus, but here is my guess at what Riordan had in mind.

Consider a forward difference table for the function $x^r$:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\color{red}{0^r} & &1^r & & 2^r & & 3^r \\ 
 & \color{red}{1^r} & & 2^r-1 & & 3^r-2^r \\
 & & \color{red}{2^r-2} & & 3^r-2 \cdot 2^r+1 \\
 & & & \color{red}{3^r - 3 \cdot 2^r + 3}
\end{array}$$

The values Riordan gives for $\Delta 0^r$, $\Delta^2 0^r$ and $\Delta^3 0^r$ appear on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Here the difference operator $\Delta$ operates on functions and is defined by J. Riordan as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\Delta f(n)&=f(n+1)-f(n)\\
\color{blue}{\Delta^2 f(n)}&=\Delta\left(f(n+1)-f(n)\right)\\
&=\Delta f(n+1)-\Delta f(n)\\
&=\left(f(n+2)-f(n+1)\right)-\left(f(n+1)-f(n)\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=f(n+2)-2f(n+1)+f(n)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
We can represent the difference operator $\Delta$ using the shift operator $E$ with $E f(n)=f(n+1)$ and the identity operator $I$ with $I f(n)=f(n)$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta}&\color{blue}{=E-I}\\
\color{blue}{\Delta f(n)}&=f(n+1)-f(n)=Ef(n)-If(n)\color{blue}{=(E-I)f(n)}
\end{align*}
We can also derive (2) using shift and identity operator as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta^2 f(n)}&=\left(E-I\right)^2f(n)\\
&=\left(E^2-2E+I\right)f(n)\\
&=E^2f(n)-2Ef(n)+If(n)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=f(n+2)-2f(n+1)+f(n)}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Now we consider the special case $f(n)=n^r$. We derive from (2) and (3)
\begin{align*}
\Delta^2 f(n)=\Delta^2 n^r=(n+2)^r-2(n+1)^r+n^r\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Evaluating (4) at $n=0$ we derive
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta^2 0^r}=2^r-2\cdot 1^r+0^r\color{blue}{=2^r-2}
\end{align*}

Similarly we obtain
\begin{align*}
\Delta^3 f(n)&=f(n+3)-3f(n+2)+3f(n+1)-f(n)\\
\Delta^3 n^r&=(n+3)^r-3(n+2)^r+3(n+1)^r-n^r\\
\color{blue}{\Delta^3 0^r}&=3^r-3\cdot 2^r+3\cdot 1^r-0^r\color{blue}{=3^r-3\cdot 2^r+3}
\end{align*}

*Note:* As J. Riordan stated, is this notation common in *[difference calculus](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Finite-difference_calculus)* which is thoroughly treated in C. Jordan's classic *[Calculus of Finite Differences](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-33)*.